# SQL- difference between column values in different rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, row

I have a table with the below structure

```
ID - Task  | Performed BY | Start Date | End Date  
1 --- Task 3 --- John --------- 9/16/2017 - 9/17/2017  
1 --- Task 2 --- Jim  ----------- 9/14/2017 - 9/16/2017  
1 --- Task 1 --- John  --------- 9/10/2107 - 9/13/2017  
2 --- Task 2 --- Jane --------- 9/14/2017 - 9/15/2017  
2 --- Task 1 --- Claire -------- 9/12/2017 - 9/13/2017
```

I need to create a new column that shows the total time (duration) taken to perform all the tasks for each ID in SQL. That is End Date of the last task minus the start date of the first task for each ID.

Below is the result that I need:

```
ID - Task  | Performed BY | Start Date | End Date | Duration  
1 --- Task 3 --- John --------- 9/16/2017 - 9/17/2017 -- 7 Days  
1 --- Task 2 --- Jim  ----------- 9/14/2017 - 9/16/2017 -- 7 Days  
1 --- Task 1 --- John  --------- 9/10/2107 - 9/13/2017 -- 7 Days  
2 --- Task 2 --- Jane --------- 9/14/2017 - 9/15/2017 -- 3 Days  
2 --- Task 1 --- Claire -------- 9/12/2017 - 9/13/2017 -- 3 Days
```

I need to use sql to perform this task. Any help on how I could achieve this task is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try using `DATEDIFF` here along with `MIN/MAX` as analytic functions:

```
SELECT
    ID, Task, [Performed By], [Start Date], [End Date],
        DATEDIFF(day,
                 MIN([Start Date]) OVER (PARTITION BY ID),
                 MAX([End Date]) OVER (PARTITION BY ID)) [Duration in Days]
FROM yourTable;
```

If I read your data correctly, the duration is given by the difference between the smallest start date and biggest end date, for a given `ID` set of records.

Comment: Thank you! I'm sure that this works in SQL. I'm still new to SAP HANA and I was under the assumption that a regular SQL query would work in HANA. Would you happen to know how I could go about partitioning in HANA?

Comment: Given that you tagged in SQL Server, you should probably open a new question if you have a similar problem on HANA.  I don't know HANA, and I can't help you there.